# Expressing I combinator and numerals via X combinator

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

So I understand that the X Combinator is defined as `X = λx (x S) K`

I am also aware of definitions of S and K and I: `S = XK` `K = X(X(X X))` `I = SKK`

Now I'm wondering how I would go about defining I via the X combinator. Is it simply subtituting `S = XK` into `I = SKK`so that we get `I = XKKK`?

Also, how would I apply X combinator to denote numerals such as 2? The church numerals define 2 as `λ f (λ x (f (f x)))`. I obtained the combinator form of 2 in terms of S, K, and I as S

Comment: As a shortcut, you can define $I$ as $SKZ$ where $Z$ is any combinator.

Comment: And yes combinators obey the leibniz property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles